# Android startActiviy in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Originally, it received the BootComplete Action and tried to start automatically when the app completes booting. However, while checking because startActivity did not work, I found out that context.startActivity executed by the Action received from BoradcastReceiver does not work.

BroadcastReceiver

```
     Intent startIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
     startIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

It's a very simple code that I can't explain, but it gets Received, but the app doesn't start. The existing apps seem to work without problems. It feels like a ghost.

There is a log like this, but I don't know what the problem is.

```
D/BootReceiver: BootRecived
D/ZLA: Setting app side flag to false due to  ActivityStarter-Normal Launch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following permission to manifest and ask for user permission once when the app opened the first time by calling
`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION));` somewhere in your app :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: how this is related?! can you elaborate more? any link to docs?

Comment: 'https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts'

Answer (score 1):

if you are targeting/running on Android 10 then it isn't possible to `startActivity`, thats Android new policy (check out [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts))

now [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive) suggest to show `Notification` and user may pick it and this will start your `Activity` (or may remove it and your app won't start)